# linq: how to divide a list into two by the sum of the values and keeping the input order

Tags: c#, linq, list

With LINQ I do not know how to split a list of items in two lists in which the sum of the values has the lowest gap possible while preserving the order of the input list.

Using this list as an example:

```
key value
 A    5
 B    2
 C    3
 D    4
 E    1
```

The result should be the following

```
list1 = A, B     (sum=7)
list2 = C, D, E  (sum=8)
```

With this other list

```
 key value
  A    1
  B    1
  C    1
  D    1
  E    9
```

The result should be the following

```
list1 = A, B, C, D  (sum=4)
list2 = E           (sum=9)
```

Thank's in advance to those who will provide me with directions.

sf

Comment: What is the result for `(A,1),(B,3),(C,1)`?

Comment: A,B - C or A - B,C equally well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for`-loop:

```
int minDelta = int.MaxValue;
var list1 = new List<ClassName>();
var list2 = new List<ClassName>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)
{
    int count = i + 1;
    int sum1 = list.Take(count).Sum(x => x.Value);
    int sum2 = list.Skip(count).Sum(x => x.Value);
    int delta = Math.Abs(sum1 - sum2);
    if (delta < minDelta)
    {
        minDelta = delta;
        list1 = list.Take(count).ToList();
        list2 = list.Skip(count).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: failing for some of the scenarios. I hope you'll find yourself :)
one is 9,2,7,1,1. Your's solution returns 11 & 9

Comment: It returns 9 & 11. But what is the correct result and why? Can you combine items which are not consecutive? I thought that the order is important, so only consecutive elements should be summed.

Comment: 10 from (2,7,1,) & 10 from (9,1). As mentioned in the question Lowest gap possible i.e. 0 not 2

Comment: @M.S.: i see, you're presuming that you can combine any elements with each other. It's not that clear. Maybe you're right. My approach splits into two consecutive groups and takes the ranges with the lowest gap. So i don't need to calculate unrelated gaps.

Comment: 9 & 11 or 11 & 9 are equally well, 
the important that it is kept the order of entry (may be alphabetic or action sequence) because it will be displayed in two columns. thank's Tim.

Comment: @stevefax I agree that 9 & 11 and 11 & 9 are equally well but as per question says Lowest gap possible and 11 & 9 or 9 &11 have 2 which is not correct. It should be 10 & 10 for (9,2,7,1,1)

Comment: @M.S.: true, but only if your assumption is correct, that all combinations are possible and not only consecutive "packages" which was my assumption.

Comment: @M.S. - 10 &10 is the absolute best combination but in this case it is necessary to hold the input sequence because they are the instructions of actions to be performed consecutively. 
Tim exact, for (9,2,7,1,1) the best combination is (9,2) + (7,1,1)  - or (9) + (2,7,1,1). thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Logic goes as:

- Fetch max item and min item (min item should not be equal to max item) from original list
- Add max item to list having smaller sum
- Remove max and min items from original lists
- last single item goes to list having lesser sum.

  ```
   List<Data> list = new List<Data>()
   {
     new Data { Key="A",Val=9 },
     new Data { Key="B",Val=1 },
     new Data { Key="D",Val=1 },
     new Data { Key="C",Val=1 },
     new Data { Key="E",Val=1 }
  };

  List<Data> list1 = new List<Data>();
  List<Data> list2 = new List<Data>();
  while (list.Any())
  {

     var max = list.Max(p => p.Val);
     var min = list.Min(p => p.Val);
     var maxItem = list.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Val == max);
     var minItem = list.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Val == min && max != min);
     if (maxItem == null)
     {
         if (list1.Sum(p => p.Val) < list2.Sum(p => p.Val))
             list1.Add(minItem);
         else
             list2.Add(minItem);
     }
     else if(minItem == null)
     {
         if (list1.Sum(p => p.Val) < list2.Sum(p => p.Val))
             list1.Add(maxItem);
         else
             list2.Add(maxItem);
     }
     else
     {
         if (list1.Sum(p => p.Val) < list2.Sum(p => p.Val))
         {
             list1.Add(maxItem);
             list2.Add(minItem);
         }
         else
         {
             list2.Add(maxItem);
             list1.Add(minItem);
         }
     }
     list.Remove(minItem);
     list.Remove(maxItem);
  }
  var sumList1 = list1.Sum(p => p.Val);
  var sumList2 = list2.Sum(p => p.Val);
  ```

Comment: incorrect result for `{7,7,7,8,14,15}`. optimal result: `7+7+7+8  = 29 = 14+15`

Comment: incorrect result for `{6,8,7,9,14,16}`. optimal result: `6+8+7+9 = 30 = 14+16`

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq and a few dictionarys (one sorted).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;



namespace ConsoleApplication85
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int index = 0;
            List<string> list1 = null;
            List<string> list2 = null;
            Dictionary<string,int> dict1  = new Dictionary<string,int>()  { 
                {"A", 5},
                {"B", 2},
                {"C", 3},
                {"D", 4},
                {"E", 1}
            };
            index = ReturnSmallestDiffIndex(dict1.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Value).ToList());
            list1 = dict1.AsEnumerable().Take(index).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
            list2 = dict1.AsEnumerable().Skip(index).Take(dict1.Count - index).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();

            Dictionary<string, int> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, int>()  { 
                {"A", 1},
                {"B", 1},
                {"C", 1},
                {"D", 1},
                {"E", 9}
            };

            index = ReturnSmallestDiffIndex(dict2.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Value).ToList());
            list1 = dict1.AsEnumerable().Take(index).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
            list2 = dict1.AsEnumerable().Skip(index).Take(dict1.Count - index).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
        }
        static int ReturnSmallestDiffIndex(List<int> input)
        {
            SortedDictionary<int, List<int>> dict = new SortedDictionary<int, List<int>>();
            for(int index = 1; index < input.Count; index++)
            {
                int diff = input.Skip(index).Take(input.Count - index).Sum() - input.Take(index).Sum();
                if(dict.ContainsKey(Math.Abs(diff)))
                {
                    dict[Math.Abs(diff)].Add(index);
                }
                else
                {
                   dict.Add(Math.Abs(diff), new List<int>() {index});
                }
            }
            return dict.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault().Value.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not efficient but Linq-heavy solution:

```
var values = new[] { 5, 2, 3, 4, 1 };
int[] sums = values.Select((element, index) => values.Skip(index).Sum()).ToArray();
int[] reverseSums = values.Select((element, index) => values.Take(index).Sum()).ToArray();
int[] diffs = sums.Select((element, index) => Math.Abs(element - reverseSums[index])).ToArray();
int minDiff = diffs.Min();

int[] firstPart = values.TakeWhile((element, index) => diffs[index] > minDiff).ToArray();
int[] lastPart = values.Skip(firstPart.Length).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"A", 5},
    {"B", 2},
    {"C", 3},
    {"D", 4},
    {"E", 1}
};

var result = Enumerable.Range(1, dict1.Count - 1).Select(i =>
    {
        var first = dict1.Take(i);
        var second = dict1.Skip(i);
        int diff = Math.Abs(first.Sum(x => x.Value) - second.Sum(x => x.Value));
        return new {First = first, Second = second, Diff = diff};
     }).OrderBy(x => x.Diff).First();

Console.WriteLine(result.Diff);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", result.First.Select(x => x.Value)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", result.Second.Select(x => x.Value)));
```

I don't know if this is the fastest way, but here is what it does:

- I try each possibility (`i` being the splitting index I iterate over)
- for every splitting index `i` I split the dictionary and calculate the diff
- I order the resulting objects by that diff
- and finally take the first one

This is of course not very performance optimized, as I have to build the sums for all possibilities. One improvement could be to start in the middle instead of `i = 1`